# How to modify the URI before redirect

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

How do I modify the URI instance `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri` before a redirect, especially the query part?

I have tried to add a middleware that modifies the request, but once I add a `CurlHandler` the response body always returns an empty string.

```
$stack = new HandlerStack();
$stack->setHandler(new CurlHandler());

$client = new Client(['handler' => $stack]);

$stack->push(Middleware::mapRequest(function (RequestInterface $request) {

  // Modify request

  return $request;
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was due to the HandlerStack type, the CurlHandler does not handle redirects by default.

How to modify the request URI

```
$stack = HandlerStack::create();

$stack->push(Middleware::mapRequest(function (RequestInterface $request) {
  // Retrieve the URI
  $uri = $request->getUri();

  $query = // update query

  // Update the URI query
  $uri = $uri->withQuery($query);

  return $request->withUri($uri);
}));
```